# multiplication with exponentials

Tags: exponentiation

How is this correct?

$$\hbar\omega e^{iHt/\hbar}\left(a_S^{\dagger}a_S+\frac{1}{2}\right)e^{-iHt/\hbar}=\hbar\omega\left(e^{iHt/\hbar}a_S^{\dagger}a_Se^{-iHt/\hbar}+\frac{1}{2}\right)$$

Source:
http://web.physics.ucsb.edu/~dfolsom/PHYS115C/HW_4_solutions_sebastian.pdf

Comment: Hint: $e^xe^{-x}=1$ for any complex $x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignoring all of the ugly symbols and replacing them with simpler ones... your question boils down to asking why

$$e^x\left(a+\frac{1}{2}\right)e^{-x} = \left(e^x a e^{-x} + \frac{1}{2}\right)$$

To see this, apply distributivity on the left to get

$$e^x\left(a+\frac{1}{2}\right)e^{-x}=\left(e^x a + e^x\frac{1}{2}\right)e^{-x}$$

Next, apply distributivity on the right to get

$$\left(e^x a + e^x\frac{1}{2}\right)e^{-x} = \left(e^x ae^{-x} + e^x\frac{1}{2}e^{-x}\right)$$

Now, remember that $\frac{1}{2}$ is just a scalar number and so multiplication with a scalar commutes so $e^x\times\dfrac{1}{2}\times e^{-x}=e^x\times e^{-x}\times\dfrac{1}{2}$

Now, remember that $e^x\times e^y = e^{x+y}$ to see that $e^x\times e^{-x}=e^0=1$ and have the $e^{x}$ and $e^{-x}$ next to the $\frac{1}{2}$ cancel eachother out which gives the desired result.

Comment: Five gods I feel a fool. Thank you good sir!

Comment: Good answer. I've edited the answer to change the left and right separately which avoids getting something like $1=1$ at the end.